# Is there a video player for Linux that has thumbnail previews?

Tags: video

When watching videos on Youtube some of them display thumbnail previews when the mouse if hovered along them time line? The picture below shows the thumbnail of the video at 3:31.

[image: Youtube video frame preview]

Some Windows video players have them as seen in the answers for this question - https://superuser.com/questions/359697, ie https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe

Are there any Linux video players with this feature?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/683329/which-media-player-has-seek-preview-with-thumbnails

Comment: Old duplicate? There is a newer question that had been answered on the same day last year: [Is there any video player which can seek with thumbnail like in YouTube?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474222/125388)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any video player which can seek with thumbnail like in YouTube?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474222/is-there-any-video-player-which-can-seek-with-thumbnail-like-in-youtube)

Comment: @PeterJ.Mello That looks like it will work. I will make the time to evaluate it. 3 years is quite a while :)