# Is there any video player which can seek with thumbnail like in YouTube?

Tags: video, vlc

When you watch a video in YouTube, you can seek it with the thumbnail preview. Many Windows' and MacOS' video players have this feature, but what about Linux's? I've already read [this same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683329/which-media-player-has-seek-preview-with-thumbnails), but the information in it seems out-of-date. [The ExMPlayer official website](http://exmplayer.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) is still alive but the project is neglected (see [git repo](https://github.com/rupeshs/ExMplayer/tree/master/src)), and actually the player doesn't work on the latest Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Is there any video player which has the feature and works on the latest linux distributions? Or must I use Windows' one with VirtualBox? If only VLC would implement this feature, but it seems that won't happen as far as I read [this](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/1251).

YouTube's seek preview:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a plugin called [mpv-thumbnail-script](https://github.com/TheAMM/mpv_thumbnail_script) for [mpv](http://mpv.io/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. It works!

Comment: According to the linked page's "issues" section, the "current" working version of the script is here: https://github.com/marzzzello/mpv_thumbnail_script

Answer (score 8):

[Ipor Sircer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474228/291779) is sufficient and perfect but let me write a step by step answer for beginners.

1. Install mpv. In Ubuntu, you can execute this command.

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt install mpv`
2. Visit [mpv-thumbnail-script releases page](https://github.com/TheAMM/mpv_thumbnail_script/releases) and download `mpv_thumbnail_script_client_osc.lua` and `mpv_thumbnail_script_server.lua`.
3. Copy these lua scripts to `~/.config/mpv/scripts/`. The directory may not exist by default.

Just following these steps, without any further configurations and with `--osc=no` option[*], the feature of the thumbnail seek is turned on. However, please note that the feature is automatically disabled when you play a video whose length is over an hour. You can again enable the feature by pressing `Shift+t` on the player or change the setting. As for the latter case, see [mpv-thumbnail-script Configurations](https://github.com/TheAMM/mpv_thumbnail_script#configuration) or execute `echo "autogenerate_max_duration=0" >> ~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/mpv_thumbnail_script.conf`.

<sub>[*]:  You can instead execute `echo "osc=no" >> ~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` once.</sub>

If you feel it takes much time to generate thumbnails, you can turn on multi-threading. It is quite easy. See again [mpv-thumbnail-script Configurations](https://github.com/TheAMM/mpv_thumbnail_script#configuration). In my case, it really works well.

My test environment:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara

$ mpv --version
mpv 0.27.2 (C) 2000-2017 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
```

(Japanese [AGMPlayer for Ubuntu](http://t-ishii.la.coocan.jp/download/AGMPlayerU.html) also worked on the same environment, though this wasn't stable.)

Comment: 06/2023: Unfortunately it didn't work for me (Macos). But this worked: `github.com/po5/thumbfast` with UI `github.com/tomasklaen/uosc`

Comment: JFYI: In my macOS environment (macOS Ventura 13.4, Apple M1, mpv 0.33.0), my answer is working well in 06/2023.

Comment: According to the linked page's "issues" section, the "current" working version of the script is here: https://github.com/marzzzello/mpv_thumbnail_script